OMNeT++ 6.1 Scavetool Filter not removing config/runattr fields
I am trying to export some OMNeT++ Simulation Results using opp_scavetool from OMNeT++ 6.1. I am only interested in the result type "vector", so I added that to my filter condition. Still, my exported CSV-R output contains runattr and config fields.
Example exported output:
run,type,module,name,attrname,attrvalue,vectime,vecvalue
udpApplications-0-20241026-11:18:29-27155,runattr,,,configname,udpApplications,,
udpApplications-0-20241026-11:18:29-27155,runattr,,,datetime,20241026-11:18:29,,
(...)
udpApplications-0-20241026-11:18:29-27155,config,,,**.numClients,10,,
udpApplications-0-20241026-11:18:29-27155,config,,,**.client[*].numApps,1,,
(...)
udpApplications-0-20241026-11:18:29-27155,vector,Network.client[0].app[0],throughput:vector,,,"0.019460136475 0.029988136475 0.040516136475 0.051044136475 0.061572136475 0.072100136475 0.082628136475 0.093156136475 0.103684136475 0.114212136475 0.124413768475 0.134415368475 0.144416968475 0.154418568475 0.164420168475 0.174411240475 0.184412840475 0.194414440475
(...)

My opp_scavetool command:
opp_scavetool export --filter "(type=~vector AND name=~throughput:vector AND module =~**.app[0])" -F CSV-R -o outfile.csv infile.vec

As you can see, I am stating to the filter that I only want vector result types, yet I get runattr and config results aswell.
What am I doing wrong here?
